# Multisite with the same domain name for different versions

Tags: multi-sites

Is it possible to have the same domain name using https with a Drupal 7 design and use http with the Drupal 6 design? If the answer is *yes*, how can I implement it?

Comment: Definitely Yes, Which web server  are you using ?

Comment: domain name for both d7 and d6 same?

Comment: Thank you @Rupesh - This is very good news for us.

We hold the number 1 position for our keywords with the D6 site and we don't want to risk loss of SERP.  On the other hand, the D7 design is responsive and updated.

Our server is Apache Version 2.2.29 at A2 Hosting

Comment: Thank you for your interest @ARUN
We use the domain offshoreww and the subdomain panama.offshoreww
The developer knows how to work with the D6 design at panama.offshoreww and the D7 design at offshoreww.  But it would make our work a lot simpler if we could keep the domain and subdomain in D6 with HTTP (as they are now) and just use 301 Redirects to the D7 design with HTTPS while keeping the same domain/subdomain names b

Comment: I don't know how much control you have on A2. But in apache, you can use **virtual hosting** separately for HTTP & HTTPS with different document root(source code) in apache configurations file.

Comment: Rupesh could we retain you to investigate that this can be implemented:

Keep our existing D6 design at HostGator with HTTP://offshoreww.com and HTTP://panama.offshoreww.com with PHP 5.4.

With PHP 5.9, place at the A2 hosting server the domains HTTPS://offshoreww.com and HTTPS://panama.offshoreww.com with the D7 design that is currently at A2 as HTTPS://asset-protection.offshoreww.com and HTTPS://panama.asset-protection.offshoreww.com. 

Use one 301 redirect from HTTP://offshoreww.com to HTTPS://offshoreww.com.